# $(this).html(), I get undefined on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem when I enter a letter I convert it to lowercase but it doesn't work for me on mobile, I get undefined.

```js
$(".letter").keyup(function(event) {
  var letter = $(this).html();
  $(this).html(letter.toLowerCase());
});
```

```css
.letter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square letter" id="16_9" data-number="1" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: I tried the above snippet in Chrome on Android and iOS, and it worked the same as a laptop.

Comment: I just tried it in Safari and it also worked.

Comment: This code doesn't work very nicely in any browser, because every time you rewrite the HTML the cursor position is reset to the beginning. So your typing is entered backwards.

Comment: It already worked for me the problem was another part of code